# Is there a way to find out which iframe is calling a parent's JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Here's an example

parent.html

```
<script>
function printWhoCalledMe() {
  console.log(???);  // what goes here that will identify the caller?
}
<iframe src="iframe1.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="iframe2.html"></iframe>
```

iframe1.html

```
<script>
window.parent.printWhoCalledMe();
</script>
```

iframe2.html

```
<script>
window.parent.printWhoCalledMe();
</script>
```

The larger question is, [I have a test harness that runs a bunch of tests, one at a time, in an iframe](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/webgl-conformance-tests.html). Each test calls `window.parent.reportOnTest(success)`

I'm looking into parallelizing the tests by running them in more than 1 iframe but I'd have to go through every test, currently 1000 tests, and change their call from `window.parent.reportOnTest(success)` to something like `window.parent.reportOnTest(success, window.location.href)` or something like that.

I'm wondering if there is a way without modifying the tests, to figure out which test is calling into the parent.

Note: I tried

```
function printWhoCalledMe() {
  console.log(window.location.href);
}
```

But that's prints the parent's href.

Comment: Might be worth investigating something via `arguments.callee.caller`, but I'm not sure off the top of my head if the function's window object is available by that route.

Answer (score 0):

i am worried you may have to use string values like that..

```
function printWhoCalledMe(callerPage) {
  console.log(callerPage);  // what goes here that will identify the caller?
}
```

and you  may call this function from your child frames with arguments like that..

iframe1.html

```
<script>
window.parent.printWhoCalledMe("iframe1");
</script>
```

iframe2.html

```
<script>
window.parent.printWhoCalledMe("iframe2");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call your parent function using `apply` you can change the context to the frame `window`

```
window.parent.printWhoCalledMe.apply(this);

function printWhoCalledMe() {
  console.log(this); // this now refers to the frame window
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So hacky, but you can use something like this:

1. Use `caller` to get a reference to the function which called your desired function.
2. Keep using `Object.getPrototypeOf` until you reach the `Object.prototype` of that realm.
3. Iterate all frame windows, and compare the `Object.prototype`
4. Once you find the match, use `frameElement` to get the iframe.

This requires sameorigin, no sandboxing, and sloppy mode. Example:

```
window.func = function func() {
  var proto, nextProto = func.caller;
  while (nextProto) {
    proto = nextProto;
    nextProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto);
  }
  var win = [].find.call(window.frames, function(win) {
    try {
      return win.Object.prototype === proto;
    } catch(err) {
      return false;
    }
  });
  if (win) {
    var iframe = win.frameElement;
    console.log("function called from frame " + iframe.name);
  }
};
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.name = "myframe";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
var doc = iframe.contentDocument;
var script = doc.createElement('script');
script.text = "(function f(){parent.func()})()";
doc.body.appendChild(script);
// Logs "function called from frame myframe"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get this information without including it in the arguments when you call the parent function.

Fortunately, this is rather easy. Assuming you give each iframe an id, you just have to pass the id of your iframe into the function you're calling. You can get the id of the iframe you're in like this: `window.frameElement.id`.

So for example:

iframe1.html

```
<script>
    window.parent.printWhoCalledMe(window.frameElement.id);
</script>
```

parent.html

```
<script>
    function printWhoCalledMe(iframeId) {
        console.log(iframeId);  // Prints the id of the iframe that called the function
    }
</script>
```